# PHP build system error in sublime text 3

Tags: php, sublimetext3, build-system

*System configuration:*

> Ubuntu 14.04 (**64 bit**) + Xampp installed (`/opt/lampp`) +  Sublime text 3 (Build 3065 )

I am trying to create **PHP Build System** inside sublime text 3 with help of [This interesting post](http://www.moreofless.co.uk/sublime-text-php-build-system/) but failed to do do. Please see my work and issue so far

Create new build via Tools > Build System > New Build System ... and save as

#### php.sublime-build

```
{
    "cmd": ["php", "-l", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "php$",
    "selector": "source.php",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}"
}
```

Now When press *Ctrl + B* or *F7* on a `.php` file it gives below error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'php' 
[cmd: ['php', '-l', '/opt/lampp/htdocs/wish/make.php']] 
[dir: /opt/lampp/htdocs/chrome] 
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]  
[Finished]
```

It seems php path issue , so added php path in that file

```
"cmd": ["/opt/lampp/bin/php", "-l", "$file"]
```

now `Ctrl+B` gives no error in the console **BUT**  gives info on status bar :
**file build finished with 1 error** (see the image below )

and it does not show the output in Sublime Text window which was expected behavior of this build system

what is the wrong here, Please correct me.

[image: screenshot]

Reference :  [Sublime text Build system](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html)

Comment: What is your theme name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved finally. below are the steps

1. Install `php5-cli`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php5-cli
   ```

   While installing , it will gives the php path something like this

   > update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php5 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in auto mode
2. Check the  command line php with a `.php` file on terminal (*Ctrl+Alt+T*)

   ```
   :~$ /usr/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/parixan/arr.php
   ```

   it executed fine
3. edit  `/home/keshav/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/`**php.build_system**

   changed the path and remove `"-l"` which was second argument

   ```
   "cmd": ["/usr/bin/php", "$file"]
   ```
4. Restart the sublime text and press `Ctrl+B` on a opened `.php` and output of that file returns in Sublime window.( expected behavior ).

Hope it help someone. :)